What's wrong with my alert when a status changes?
I'm new to Grafana, and quickly realizing I may not have a great grasp on how alerts and/or Prometheus data are evaluated, so forgive my ignorance. I've tried to set up an alert, but it never fires. Other alerts do fire though.
I have a value from Prometheus, vastai_machine_gpu_idle. This value is usually either 8 or 0. I'm trying to set up an alert when that value changes.
My query (A) is delta(vastai_machine_gpu_idle[$__rate_interval]), and I have two expressions which I don't understand very well:
B - Reduce: Input: A, Function: Last, Mode: Strict
C - Threshold: Input: B, Is outside range: 0 to 0

Intuitively it seems like this should work? The way I assume this works is that alert conditions are evaluated every 15 seconds (in my case), and so delta(vastai_machine_gpu_idle[$__rate_interval]) returns the difference between what vastai_machine_gpu_idle was 15 seconds ago vs now; in some cases this will be 8, in others it will be -8. The part where I'm less sure are the expressions.
Any ideas why this may not be firing or any advice on how I could learn?

I'm confused by last sentence of the question: does your setup work or not? If not what exactly qualifies as "not working"?

If you have problems with alerts simply not being created - check invalid settings. You mentioned 15s for evaluation - but I think screenshot says it's actually 5m. Also iiuc, 5m pending time will reset all possible alerts unless rate_interval is significantly large (and i dont believe this is the case here)

I apologize, I updated my post to clarify. The alert is being created, but never fires. Other alerts do fire though.

Yeah, that's better, thanks. my point regarding intervals still stands: you have evaluation interval and pending period of 5m. At least latter is way to long, if understand what is happening correctly.

I've changed the evaluation interval and pending period to 1m with no success. I'm definitely lacking understanding as to why this matters though, as I assume we're comparing values 5 (now 1) minutes ago to values now, and if they're different the alert should fire.
